# Not so Simple? Substitution Cipher

Tags: cipher

Once more the shores of the island of Pohnpei have been the scene of strange fogs, strange smells, and equally strange newly discovered carvings. The previous carvings have widely been thought to be have a hoax. They were quite easy to decipher. The following, however, was carved in the same cliff, atop where the previous carvings were. Those previous carvings have disappeared as mysteriously as they had appeared, overnight, after a mysterious fog, which incidentally left the area smelling of bacon, engulfed the island, again. After the fog had cleared, there they were.
As before, the next evening certain letters were seen to glow blue.

it's still possible the same dodgy individual(s) may be responsible. There's still obviously punctuation.

However, the text is very... different.
[image]

If this new text can be deciphered... it is beyond the skill of anyone on the island, including myself...

If you wish to skip past deciphering the script itself, or you wish to work in a text editor, you will find a transcript below, minus the color changes:

> `( Fhat gb gur ghar bs “Ure Znwrfgl” ol gur Orngyrf )`
>  `Zygznummag'y gt grokt muj haz nk jukyt'z ngbk g ruz zu yge.`
>  `Onvocjbbpv'n vi vgdzi bjy wpo cz ngphwzmn amjh yvt oj yvt.`
>          `U imzzm iadetub uz tue zqngxage rmzq,`
>         `Ngf U oagxpz'f sqf m emoduruoq uz fuyq.`
>  `Srzsgnfftz'r zm zkhdm fnc ats mnv gd'r fnmmz bqzbj lx rohmd,`
>                          `Ng xdzg,`
>  `Mnv gd'r fnmmz bqzbj lx... *bqtmbg rgqhdj rktqo zqfg zhddd*`

Comment: Do you have a text transcription of the symbols (just using arbitrary letters for each symbol, and capital/lowercase for black/blue, for instance)?

Comment: I ask because transcribing all of this seems pretty tedious. From the off-white cursor in the middle of line 3, it appears that you did type this -- it would be much less unnecessarily time-consuming for the solvers if you could give a transcription (with the characters reassigned randomly if necessary).

Comment: I have added a transcript, however, the script is indeed a font and without the font accessible here as a web font it will show up as normal text. I was unable to get the bold or italics to wok in conjunction with existing punctuation in the text and also preserve the look. However, the text is easily moved into word or another text editor and the colors can be copied over,
It should not be necessary though, as the color variations should be easy to interpret without having to include it in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors

> are a message in the Bacon cipher, taking A as blue and B as black. The message starts "ROT SIX", and continues to give instructions for decoding the rest. (Or at least, I assume it does: it's fairly easy to skip most of this step.)

The text appears to be

> random Caesar shifts of the following:
>
>    ( Sung to the tune of “Her Majesty” by the Beatles )
>  Tsathoggua's an alien god but he doesn't have a lot to say.
>  Tsathoggua's an alien god but he slumbers from day to day.
>               I wanna worship in his nebulous fane,
>         But I couldn't get a sacrifice in time.
>  Tsathoggua's an alien god but now he's gonna crack my spine,
>                          Oh yeah,
>   Now he's gonna crack my... *crunch shriek slurp argh aieee*
>
>  The rest of the color Bacon cipher probably tells the other shift numbers, but I haven't fully decoded it. (I just bruteforced each line - there are only 26 options, and it's easy to scan through all of them.)